# Haskell foldr over infinite list, using head

Tags: haskell, infinite, fold

```
f :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f n acc = ([length $ head acc] ++ (take n $ repeat n)) : acc
```

I am trying to understand how

```
take 2 $ foldr f undefined [0..]
```

gives

```
[[2],[3,1]]
```

I am able to transform up to here, and then get stuck

```
foldr f undefined [0..]
foldr f undefined ([0:[1..])
f 0 $ foldr f undefined [1..]
f 0 $ foldr f undefined (1: [2..])
f 0 $ f 1 $ foldr f undefined [2..]
f 0 $ f 1 $
```

Answer (score 4):

You will never see anything interesting if you only expand `foldr` calls. Once a call to `f` is the head of your expression, expand `f` instead. That expansion will require some amount of information from its `acc`, which is the trailing `foldr` call, but it won't need *all* of it, so you'll be able to make progress.

```
...
f 0 $ 
([length $ head (foldr f undefined [1..])] ++ (take 0 $ repeat 0)) : foldr f undefined [1..]
...
```

Here I've repeated `foldr f undefined [1..]` twice because `acc` is used twice, but of course you need only expand it once, using the same result in both places.

Answer (score 3):

From `f 0 $ f 1 $ foldr f undefined [2..]`, continue for one more iteration, then simply inline the definition of `f`:

```
f 0 $ f 1 $ foldr f undefined [2..]
f 0 $ f 1 $ f 2 $ foldr f undefined [3..] -- below let rest = foldr f undefined [3..]
f 0 $ f 1 $ f 2 $ rest
f 0 $ f 1 $ (\n acc -> ([length $ head acc] ++ (take n $ repeat n)) : acc) 2 $ rest
f 0 $ f 1 $ (([length $ head rest] ++ (take 2 $ repeat 2)) : rest)
f 0 $ f 1 $ (([length $ head rest] ++ [2,2]) : rest)
f 0 $ f 1 $ ([length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
f 0 $ (\n acc -> ([length $ head acc] ++ (take n $ repeat n)) : acc) 1 $ ([length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
f 0 $ (([length $ head ([length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)] ++ (take 1 $ repeat 1)) : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
f 0 $ (([length $ [length $ head rest,2,2]] ++ [1]) : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest) 
-- this is the crux, we don't need to evaluate rest to evaluate the length here
f 0 $ (([3] ++ [1]) : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
f 0 $ ([3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
((\n acc -> ([length $ head acc] ++ (take n $ repeat n)) : acc) 0 $ ([3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)
([length $ head ([3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest)] ++ (take 0 $ repeat 0)) : [3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest
([length $ [3,1]] ++ []) : [3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest
[length $ [3,1]] : [3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest
[2] : [3,1] : [length $ head rest,2,2] : rest
```

Now since we only want the first two element (`take 2`), we get
`[[2],[3,1]]`

Comment: It would be great if there were a click-through tool to aid in the expansions.  The expansions are purely mechanical, but can be a little daunting.  Thanks all.